# Why were my answers on Thrust library deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-answers

I am new and gave a couple of answers related to 
CUDA programming (in particular Thrust library). But my answers
were deleted:

- [Finding the number of occurrences of keys and the positions of first occurrences of keys by CUDA Thrust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792926/finding-key-frequency-and-distinct-key-positions-in-a-sorted-key-vector-with-thr/11627003#11627003)
- [Thrust vectorized search: Efficiently combine lower_bound and binary_search to find both position and existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124764/thrust-vectorized-search-efficiently-combine-lower-bound-and-binary-search-to-f/11642703#11642703)

Were my answers off-topic?
This was about Thrust library, I suggested an alternative
solution (which is actually working faster according to benchmarks)
and it's also free, same as Thrust library, 
so what's the problem?

Comment: You need to be careful when you link to 3rd party sites or it may be considered self-promotional spam.

Comment: I have nothing to do with this company myself. But I have pretty much experience with CUDA and GPGPU porogramming, here is my webpage: http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~emeliyan. You can write me a email on the address given there to check my identity.

I found this library (Arrayfire) on some forum and it seems to be a good alternative for Thrust, but not many people knows about it..

Is there any way to restore my answers ?

Comment: I'm not accusing you of anything. In fact, I actually don't agree with the deletions. But if I had to guess why the moderator deleted them, it's because (at first glance), it looks like you have an undisclosed affiliation with that link.

Comment: I can only say that I am not affiliated with this link whatsoever: the company which develops Arrayfire is based in the US while I live in Germany, they do not even have offices in Europe according to the website

Comment: @asm I don't know if this is the cause, but I recall we had a user somewhat spamming Arrayfire before. Perhaps your content looked similar and therefore suspicious to those active in the tag.

Comment: @asm - There are lots of new users coming here, making several posts on their first day, recommending the same product in all their posts. Most often they **are** affiliated. Most often the posts are deleted. Your posts might have matched this pattern.

Answer (score 14):

As Bart pointed out in his comment, we recently had a problem with users affiliated with AccelerEyes excessively promoting their ArrayFire library in dozens of answers. Someone flagged your answers as continuing in this trend, and given that every answer you left was complimentary of this library, they were assumed to be part of this and removed.

I looked into this, and I can see that you don't appear to be associated with those who were promoting ArrayFire before, so I've undeleted your answers. Even the case of the AccelerEyes folks doing this was a tricky one, because it does seem to be a good library for some of these cases, but they were a little overzealous in promoting it.

One thing I might caution is to avoid going around and only providing recommendations for this library in questions that don't ask about alternatives like this. It really starts to look like astroturfing if every answer by a new user recommends a commercial library, particularly if the question was about how to do something in another library.

Comment: ok thanks for clarification, I won't recommend this library anymore unless someone really looking for alernatives

Answer (score 11):

I can only guess, but it *looks* to me like *astroturfing* -- basically disguised advertisements posted  as if they came from a user. The reason they look this way is because you're a brand new user, and your first two posts said something very similar, along the lines of "You should try X instead of the thing you asked about," for a constant value of X.

Anyway, even if your intentions are good, the posts *still* might not be welcome; you say yourself above that your intention is to publicize this tool that "not many people know about," and that's advertising, and that's just not welcome. Write some blog posts, or buy some banner ads someplace, but the general approach of suggesting a product you like as an alternative to what people asked about is questionable at best.

Comment: ok I understand your point, it looks suspicious because I am a new user.. 
anyway if this were an advertisement, how would it be benefitial to me ?
I am not affiliated with Arrayfire: I am based in Germany (my webpage is given above) while 
this company is from the US and does not even have offices in Europe.

Comment: Furthermore, I am not suggesting people to use something
completely different, e.g.: "You should not use CUDA, try Intel's TBB instead!"
Thrust and Arrayfire are based on the same CUDA framework anyway.

Also, I am giving a concrete solution (code), not just vague 
recommendations: "You should try X instead of Y because I think it's better.."
Sometimes people just think there is only one Thrust library for high-level
GPGPU programming and there are no alternatives..

Comment: Remember, I didn't delete the posts myself, I'm just giving you an educated guess as to what might have happened. Chances are good that some user flagged your posts as possible spam, and a moderator acted on those flags; that's the way it usually works.

Comment: I disagree that publicizing a useful tool, especially if it is a good fit for the problem, is wrong. That should not be the message sent. @asm As far as I can tell, the only reason that the mod deleted it is because the ratio of code to text is very high, so the posts were automatically flagged as possible "low quality" (this is common from random users who just dump large blocks of code and ask a question in an answer). Combined with the two automatic flags, possible flags from others, a brand new user and the same library being mentioned in both answers, the mod must've thought it was spam.

Comment: Well said and well guessed, Brad has just officially confirmed this. :)